# using beautifulsoup and regex to get date from string, getting None at the moment

Tags: python, regex, date, beautifulsoup

So when I write out my text I'm able to capture the date in the following format:

```
text = "The event takes place from May 14-June 11, 2018"
match = re.search(r'(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}\-(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}', text).group()
print(match)
'May 14-June 11, 2018'
```

But what I really want is to use beautifulsoup and regex to extract the date from anywhere in the html page but I can't seem to replicate my success above although the text definitely exists in the html. I'm a novice, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

```
open_page = driver.get(url)
html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
date = soup.find(text=re.compile('(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}\-(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}'))
print(date)
'None'
```

I also tried:

```
html_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text().strip()
match = re.search(r'(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2}\-(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4}', text)
print(match)
'None'
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="event--date">
       The event takes place from May 14-June 11, 2018        </div>
```

But I don't want to rely on tags because I will be doing this across domains.

And when I print

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text().strip()
print(text)
'@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}


The event takes place from May 14–June 11, 2018    '
```

Comment: Does the file actually have a date? If so, please include the relevant HTML fragment in your question.

Comment: edited with the html

Comment: Could you print what is the value of text? Just trying to verify whether it parsed the html correctly or not.

Comment: I tried `re.search` and `soup.find` with your HTML fragment and got the expected date.

Comment: Ah I got it to work, it was because of it being the long dash instead of the short dash. thanks for the help!

Comment: As a side note: if you needed the raw string literal (`r` prefix) in the `re.search`, you almost certainly need it in the `re.compile`, given that they're exactly the same literal characters.

Comment: In response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51639369/5211833) deleting your own questions is fine when the system allows you, but please do not vandalise them. You granted license of your post to Stack Overflow when posting it. Deleting the question removes it from view (for those with <10k rep) and is sufficient. People will roll back the question to the previous state when a question is vandalised.